# Cannot find file ReactRefreshEntry.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, lerna

I have a monorepo that uses lerna, in that monorepo i have one api and two frontends, in both projects i have the same exact error when starting the projects

> project: multi C:/Users/userName/programing/work/myProject/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js C:/Users/userName/programing/work/myProject/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js ./src/index.jsx
> project: Cannot find file: 'ReactRefreshEntry.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 'C:\Users\UserName\programing\work\myProject\node_modules@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\client\work'.

I already tried

- uninstalling/updating/deactivating react devtools extension
- deleting the hole project and installing all again
- recovering dependencies

as additional information
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz
Node: 14.15.1
Yarn: 1.22.5
Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (96.0.1054.62)
react: 17.0.2 react-dom: 17.0.2 
react-scripts: 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved, the problem was the name of the folder that contains the project folder, how I'm in windows and windows is case insensitive I can enter the directory if a have one mayus where it isn't supossed and that was causing the error